# calling a function and passing it values in a struct

Tags: c++

so i have this structure:

```
// Structure used to define a point (x,y) in the grid.
typedef struct
{
    int x, y;
} Point;
```

and this function

```
Sequence getSequence(int grid[][MAXCOLS], Point startPos)
{
    // Create an empty sequence
    Sequence emptySeq;
    emptySeq.size = 0;

    // Use the empty sequence to start the recursive function
    return generateSeq(grid, startPos, emptySeq);
}
```

i do not know the position where the sequence begins. so i have too call on the getSequence function 16 times in main, so that you can pass each of the 16 grid positions to it as possible starting positions.

i've tried this but it didnt work.

```
getSequence(grid, x.0, y.0 );
```

can someone please show me how to call on the getSequence in main. Im new to programing

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straight forward method would be to create an instance of `Point` as Arun said like so:

```
int main()
{
   Point p1 ;
   // create grid here

   p1.x = 0 ;
   p1.y = 0 ;
   getSequence( grid, p1 );
}
```

If you can use `C++11` then you can also do this:

```
 getSequence( grid, {0,0} );
```

To be more like `C++`-like, though you really should use a `constructor` like so:

```
class Point
{
     public:
     int x, y;

     Point( int a = 1, int b = 1 ) : x(a) , y(b) {} 
} ;
```

Also then you should think about making `x` and `y` to be `private` as well but your particular example starts getting more complicated then. If you have a `constructor` your `16` calls becomes slightly easier since you can do this:

```
 getSequence( grid,  Point(1,1) );
 getSequence( grid,  Point(2,2) );
```

Or you could use a loop as well, the values of `a` and `b` will depend on your application:

```
for( int a = 0, b = 0; a < 5; ++a, ++b)
{
   getSequence(grid, Point(a,b) );
}
```

Comment: can i just use a loop go through the positions? or do i have to do this 16 times changing the x and y values each time? :
      
 ` startPos.x=0; 
 startPos.y=0;
 getSequence(grid, startPos);`

Comment: @user1896464 added some more details that hopefully provide a good answer

Comment: do i have to do this 16 times: getSequence( grid,  Point(1,1) );
or can i just use a loop to change the numbers?

Comment: @user1896464 Added another addition with a loop that you could use, hopefully it is easy to modify for your needs

Comment: You don't need two constructors; one with default arguments would suffice.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Yeah, I was trying to be a little more general, do you think it is confusing having both?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I'm not sure "confusing" is the word I'd use, but should `Point` be extended to cope with three dimensions (say `int z` is added), it would be better to minimise the number of constructors to modify.

Comment: In your amendment, I think you meant, "`Point( int a = 1, int b = 1) : x(a) , y(b) {}`" (or similar).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answers, you could give `Point` a constructor:

```
struct Point
{
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){}
    int x, y;
}
```

Then do:

```
getSequence(grid, Point(0, 0));
```

That will remove the need to explicitly construct (or modify) a `Point` object every time you want to call the function, and IMO is more readable since the purpose of `Point` in this context is merely a parameter to `getSequence`.

Note: the `typedef` keyword in front of `struct` is [unnecessary in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/1227469).

Comment: +1 we were literally writing the same thing at the same time, great advice beyond the basic question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of Point and pass it to getSequence method.

```
    Point gridpoint; 
    gridpoint.x = 0;
    gridpoint.y = 0;
    getSequence(grid, gridpoint);
    // Use gridpoint here
```